# Diferencia entre datadir y innodb_data_home_dir

Tags: mysql

¿Alguien me puede explicar la diferencia entre `datadir` y `innodb_data_home_dir` en mysql?

Acabo de instalar **Mysql 5.7** en una máquina **linux**.

Según el tutorial de [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) lo adecuado es separar los ficheros de datos y de log

El fichero my.cnf tiene la siguiente configuración:

> datadir=/var/lib/mysql
>
> innodb_data_home_dir = /mysql/data
>
> innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:50M:autoextend
>
> innodb_log_group_home_dir = /mysql/log

Es correcta esta configuración?

Gracas

Comment: Puede que encuentres en este libro la información que necesitas:
https://books.google.com.cu/books?id=OWxUAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA555&lpg=PA555&dq=diferencias+entre+datadir+y+innodb_data_home_dir+mysql&source=bl&ots=WjneczwjdE&sig=1ouvQeMJc0tlmN-trdJfEw_OjiE&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF85_2mobUAhXEZiYKHX6iBawQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=diferencias%20entre%20datadir%20y%20innodb_data_home_dir%20mysql&f=false

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB tiene dos modos de funcionamiento: Si `innodb_file_per_table = 0` todos los datos se almacenan en uno o varios archivos de espacios de tablas `ibdata` centrales. Si `innodb_file_per_table = 1` los datos se almacenan en archivos .ibd. El archivo central de tablas debe seguir existiendo, pero sólo almacena los datos administrativos y el registro de deshacer.

Los archivos centrales de espacios de tablas se crean en `innodb_data_home_dir`, a menos que se especifiquen con rutas completas. Si `innodb_data_home_dir` está vacía, entonces se utilizará `datadir`

Los archivos de espacios de tablas individuales se especifican con una sintaxis magia dentro de `innodb_data_file_path` (ver más detalles en el enlace al final). La cadena por defecto es "`ibdata1: 10M: autoextend`", que creará 10 millones de archivos `ibdata1` nombrados en `datadir`.

Usted debe estar operando con `innodb_file_per_table = 1` para obtener un archivo por cada tabla. Esto le permite recuperar espacio en disco en el nivel de sistema operativo con `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Si necesita o desea usar `innodb_file_per_table = 0` tendrá un archivo `ibdata1` muy grande. Asegúrese de que su sistema operativo y herramientas de copia de seguridad pueden tratar convenientemente con tales archivos de gran tamaño. Si ese no es el caso puede que sea necesario tener una declaración `innodb_data_file_path` más complicado indicando el límite de tamaño que deben tener esos archivos.

`datadir` representa el directorio de datos de MySQL que se especificó como una opción de configuración cuando se compila mysqld (normalmente `/usr/local/mysql/data` para una instalación binaria o `/usr/local/var` para una instalación de origen).

### Ejemplo de configuración avanzado

Suponiendo un ordenador con Linux, 2 GB de RAM y 60 GB de tres discos duros (en rutas de directorios  `/`, `/dr2` y `/dr3`). El ejemplo siguiente muestra posibles parámetros de configuración en `my.cnf` para InnoDB:

```
[mysqld]
# You can write your other MySQL server options here
# ...
innodb_data_home_dir =
#
# Data files must be able to hold your data and indexes
innodb_data_file_path = /ibdata/ibdata1:2000M;/dr2/ibdata/ibdata2:2000M:autoextend
#
# Set buffer pool size to 50-80% of your computer's memory,
# but make sure on Linux x86 total memory usage is < 2GB
set-variable = innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
set-variable = innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /dr3/iblogs
#
# innodb_log_arch_dir must be the same as innodb_log_group_home_dir
# (starting from 4.0.6, you can omit it)
innodb_log_arch_dir = /dr3/iblogs
set-variable = innodb_log_files_in_group=2
#
# Set the log file size to about 25% of the buffer pool size
set-variable = innodb_log_file_size=250M
set-variable = innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
#
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
set-variable = innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
#
# Uncomment the next lines if you want to use them
#innodb_flush_method=fdatasync
#set-variable = innodb_thread_concurrency=5
```

Observa que el ejemplo se colocan los dos archivos de datos en discos diferentes. InnoDB llenará el espacio de tabla comenzando con el primer archivo de datos. En algunos casos, se mejorará el rendimiento de la base de datos si todos los datos no se coloca en el mismo disco físico. Poner los archivos de registro en un disco diferente de los datos es muy a menudo beneficioso para el rendimiento. También puede usar particiones de disco en bruto (dispositivos en bruto) como archivos de datos InnoDB, que puede acelerar la I / O. Vea la sección "[Uso de dispositivos básicos para espacios de tablas](http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/db/mysql/File-space-management.html#InnoDB-Raw-Devices)".

---

Para más detalles puedes consultar las páginas siguientes, aunque todas están en inglés:

- [InnoDB Configuration: documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-configuration.html)
- [InnoDB Configuration, con ejemplos](http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/db/mysql/InnoDB-configuration.html)
- [Configuring InnoDB - An InnoDB tutorial](http://mysqldump.azundris.com/archives/78-Configuring-InnoDB-An-InnoDB-tutorial.html)

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!